# Are games able to see my ROUTER or MODEM's Mac address?

Tags: networking, router, mac, vpn

I've carefully searched this forum and I found numerous duplicate questions asking about whether mac addresses are visible to websites or games. But those questions all pertained to the mac address of the computer. My concern is about the mac address of the router or modem.

The reason this matters is, I'm switching to a new computer. So my computer's mac address will be different. So I won't be trackable via my old computer's mac address. But I'm not planning to replace my modem or my router, so my modem and router mac addresses will be the same. I will however, be using a VPN to change my IP. But even with the VPN, I'm wondering if games could still potentially detect me, if they are able to see my router or my modem's mac address, even despite the VPN? Thanks.

PS. For anyone wondering, I'm not cheating. Rather, I'm playing a game which I suspect is tracking players's daily play hours, and rigging games to be more difficult for players who play more, and making games easier for casual players. To test my theory, I want to bypass this tracking. So I'm getting multiple computers, a VPN, and multiple accounts. The only concern then, is whether my router or modem's mac address could somehow give me away. And since I'm putting money into this test (the computers aren't free), I don't want to mess around with ANY chance I'll be tracked.

Comment: I'll say it's possible, as you can definitely tell the MAC address of your default gateway (your router) from your computer with ARP. There's nothing prevent a program from gathering such information and upload it to a server I think.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.

If you installed the game on your computer, then you have given them near complete access to your computer.  They can potentially see and access ***everything*** on your computer and network.  That is a risk you take  when you install software.

If this a browser based game, you still can be tracked by your network information.  However, that type of information is very unreliable and not solely how websites track users.  IPs change often, MACs can be changed on any device, VPNs are common, etc.  You are now more likely to be tracked by cookies, browser fingerprinting, and various other methods on the web.